# SQL SERVER 2008 R2 DBCC PAGE PUZZLED

Tags: sql-server-2008, dbcc

i did a test about DBCC IND and DBCC page .
Engine: SQL Server 2008

**Script:**

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t2
(
ID int,
Col1 varchar(10),
Col2 varchar(20)
);


INSERT INTO dbo.t2 SELECT 1,REPLICATE('a',10),REPLICATE('b',10)


DECLARE @DBID int,@TableID int;
SELECT @DBID=DB_ID(),@TableID=OBJECT_ID('dbo.t2');
DBCC IND(@DBID,@TableID,-1)
```

--this shows :
1 274 1 278 1307151702 0 1 72057594039107584 In-row data 1

```
DBCC TRACEON (3604)
--DBCC PAGE (@DBID, 1,22,3)
--then dump the page info
DBCC PAGE(@DBID, 1,274,1)
```

shows:

DATA:

Slot 0, Offset 0x60, Length 51, DumpStyle BYTE

Record Type = PRIMARY_RECORD Record Attributes = NULL_BITMAP VARIABLE_COLUMNS VERSIONING_INFO
Record Size = 51 
Memory Dump @0x000000000F7EA060

0000000000000000: 70000800 01000000 03000002 001b0025 †p..............% 
0000000000000010: 00616161 61616161 61616162 62626262 †.aaaaaaaaaabbbbb 
0000000000000020: 62626262 **62000000 00000000 00310000** †bbbbb........1.. 
0000000000000030: **00000**†††††††††††††††††††††††††††††††...

OFFSET TABLE:

Row - Offset 
0 (0x0) - 96 (0x60)
i try to explain:

**byte one**
0x70 01110000

BIT 0: SQL SERVER 2005/2008

BIT 1-3 :PRIMARY DATA

BIT 4 : HAS NULL

BIT 5:HAS VAR

BIT 6:NOT USED

BIT 7: NOT GHOST

**Second Byte**

0x00 : NOT USED

**Thrid Byte**

0x0008 :offset 8

the fix length int ,i got value **1**

then next byte

0300 : 3 columns

00 : not null

0002 :2 columns

var column endoffset 0x001B (i got value aaa....)

var column end offset 0x0025 (i got value bbbb...)

but ,i don's know the meaning about last bytes....

please help me ,thks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's the 14-byte versioning tag [timestamep, pointer into tempdb].

Comment: the snapshot isolation use the versioning bytes?

Comment: but i select * from sys.databases ,i never set read committed snapshot or allow snapshot isolation

Comment: Each database row may use up to 14 bytes at the end of the row for row versioning information. The row versioning information contains the transaction sequence number of the transaction that committed the version and the pointer to the versioned row. These 14 bytes are added the first time the row is modified, or when a new row is inserted, under any of these conditions:

READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT or ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION options are ON.

The table has a trigger.

Multiple Active Results Sets (MARS) is being used.

Online index build operations are currently running on the table.

Answer (score 0):

From the master, Paul Randal

[Inside the Storage Engine: Anatomy of a page](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-page.aspx). And [Extent](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-an-extent.aspx). And [Record](http://www.sqlskills.com/BLOGS/PAUL/post/Inside-the-Storage-Engine-Anatomy-of-a-record.aspx)

It's part of the Record, as per comments to last link.

Answer (score 0):

Each database row may use up to 14 bytes at the end of the row for row versioning information. The row versioning information contains the transaction sequence number of the transaction that committed the version and the pointer to the versioned row. These 14 bytes are added the first time the row is modified, or when a new row is inserted, under any of these conditions:

READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT or ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION options are ON.

The table has a trigger.

Multiple Active Results Sets (MARS) is being used.

Online index build operations are currently running on the table.